# Can somebody help me modifying an open-source software (KeePass)?

Tags: c#, png, icons, alphablending

Do you know of KeePass Password Safe 2? It's open-source and I'm trying to do some things but I've hit a dead end and can't find where the code is doing this and why it's doing it at all.

The source code is here and it's coded in C#:
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/keepass/KeePass-2.08-Source.zip

The problem is that the icons of the TreeView nodes and ListView entries are not properly rendered if the come from an alpha-blended PNG file. For instance, I created a 16x16 image and filled with a solid red color but with 50% transparency and saved it as PNG. Then added this icon to one of the TreeView nodes and KeePass displays this icon in a grayish color.

I'm not the author of this application as you know and can't post specific blocks of codes as I don't know which one might be causing the problem and like I said, I have no idea where this is coming from.

Can anybody help me out here?

**EDIT:**
I think I've found the issue here: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AlphaImageImagelist.aspx

Comment: If it is not abandoned piece of software, why don't you cooperate with its maintainer?

Comment: And I am but he's on vacation for two weeks and I kinda wanted to have this fixed before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do use KeePass 2.x to store all my credentials. Haven't had a chance to look at the source code, though.

I think your question would be more suitable when asked in the [KeePass forums](http://sourceforge.net/forum/?group_id=95013). Maybe they're already working on a fix ? You might be also able to contribute to the development of the program.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do and kinda need to fix the problem I described but can't seem to do it. And not many people seems to go to those forums... :/

Answer (score 0):

This is more like an issue with the common controls KeePass is using rather than a problem in the KeePass code itself. A Google search turned up [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ffe7cab1-bc9d-4562-8cb0-169ffa736595) in the MSDN; there's a lot of duplicated posts but it seems to suggest that you need to set the EnableVisualStyles property on the form to get alpha transparency to work.

Comment: Application.EnableVisualStyles() is already called as the first line in main() and I don't think there's a property named "EnableVisualStyles" for Forms.

Comment: My mistake, it *is* a method on the Application object, not the Form